# Scheduled parsing of XML feed into wp_insert_post()

Tags: rest-api, feed, cron

I coded a custom theme that parses and imports into a CPT the content of some multi page XML feeds.
This it the current workflow:

- daily action scheduled for 2am with [action-scheduler](https://actionscheduler.org/api/) to process all the feeds
- for each feed, parse it's URL to get all the pages in the feed, then enqueue (with action-scheduler) the import of the feed page
- **in a single run**, parse the XML feed (with [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)), get each element from the feed, process it and ultimately insert the element data with wp_insert_post(), update_field() and wp_insert_term(); at the end, enqueue the import of the next feed page

To make sure these actions are running even without WP visitors:

- I set up a short script running via the cPanel cron and accessing a REST API endpoint - if the script receives 0, it stops, for any other code it sleeps for 30 seconds and then accesses the API endpoint again
- in WP, the function handling the API checks if there any actions need to be processed, in which case it returns a specific code, or 0 in case nothing is pending.

This worked well until I got to some 6k posts in WP. Then the whole process stopped in error when some pages exceeded 300 seconds of run time. Although I increased PHP's max_execution_time beyond this value, I found out that the 300 seconds hardcoded limit [would be a *feature* (?!), and not a bug of action scheduler](https://github.com/woocommerce/action-scheduler/issues/203).

Combined with this, I also received the request to do the import more often than once per day. So now I intend to break my large **single run** into individual steps, one for each element / post.

For these individual steps, though, I am looking for something different than action scheduler, something that would allow me this procedure:

```
- Step N: run the step N processing, checks, inserts;
- Step N: call the step N+1 => if it answers OK, exit, else enqueue an action and exit
- Step N+1: answer OK
- Step N+1: run the step ...
...
```

Would this be possible in WP, and if YES, what tools should I look into. If not, what would be the best way to approach this?